# Start Rails on system startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have a problem with my Ruby on Rails installation. I installed Ruby with RVM, then used `gem install rails` to install Rails. The `rails` command worked in terminal, but if I close the terminal and try using `rails` again it gives me an error:

```
grega@spaceship:~$ rails -v
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Using `rvm -v` or `ruby -v` works.

```
grega@spaceship:~$ rvm -v

rvm 1.18.21 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

grega@spaceship:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

To get rails working again I have to execute `source .rvm/scripts/rvm`

RVM is added to the .bashrc file: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

Am I forgetting something, that prevents me from using rails on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your bashrc :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```